# how to hide progress bar in html5 video player

Tags: html, css

this is my code :

```
<video width="720" height="576" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://test.com/test.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

i use html5 player for play mp4 online , but i need hide process bar by css or others .

this is my css code :

```
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

thank you

Comment: Do you need to add just the progress bar, or all controls?

Answer (score 1):

To remove only the scrub bar use the below code:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```